# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined while trying to click send button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’ve tried to search for solutions but could not find any that suited my code.

I have many different categories on my website. While trying to add new ad post [here is the link](https://yala.xyz/add/).

```
    form.find('.info-tooltip-container').addClass('hidden');

    var firstErrorMessageTop = form.find('.error-tooltip-container, .main-form-error').first().offset().top;

    if (!form.hasClass('ajax-form-no-scrolling')) {
      $(window).scrollTop(firstErrorMessageTop - 10);
    }

  }

  if (response.status == 'success') {
    if (callback == 'addCallBack') {
      window[callback](response.aid, response.step);
    }
    else if (callback == 'editCallBack') {
      window[callback](response.aid);
    }
  }
});
```

All other categories work fine, except `Category: Job » IT / telecom / computers`. When I try to send I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

[image: Google chrome console log]

Can someone tell me what’s wrong?

Comment: and tagging this with CSS and PHP for what reason ?

Comment: Is this is a question please try to provide minimum code without code no one will help you.

Comment: `form.find('.error-tooltip-container, .main-form-error')` returns 0 elements. Check your selectors and HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide mush information, but from your screenshot the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`
is coming from the file `release.js?v=2` line `65`.

So by looking at the source code the problem is coming from the line : 
`var firstErrorMessageTop = form.find('.error-tooltip-container, .main-form-error').first().offset().top;`

so probably `offset()` returned undefined here, try checking for that

```
var firstErrorMessage = form.find('.error-tooltip-container, .main-form-error').first();
var firstErrorMessageTop = firstErrorMessage && firstErrorMessage.offset() && firstErrorMessage.offset().top ? firstErrorMessage.offset().top : 0;
```

Comment: How can i ignore it and let it contented the submit ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Did you try the two lines I give you ?